# AWS Cloudwatch logs auto scroll

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am collecting logs from AWS Cloudwatch.
I have selected a log stream and a regex expression for which I want to collect logs.

I have to select all the logs for some duration, but the issue is the logs are loaded  for one second at a time so have to do a lot of scrolling which becomes irritating.

Could anyone suggest some way of loading all the logs for certain time period at one go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing this in the amazon cloudwatch web console, and if you don't want to scroll. You can paste this code snippet in your browser dev console to scroll at one second intervals.

```
let scroll = setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('logs__main')[0].scrollTo(0, 999999999)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I love the creativity of laziness :-)